# How to fix Session timeout issue?

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

We have a Struts 2 application.
Our javascripts issues automatic, periodic polling requests (Ajax), in order to keep the view  up-to-date.

Unfortunately this prevents sessions from timing out...

Is there a way to tell server that some URL shouldn't affect session timeouts?

Namely if for the last 30 minutes, the browser requested nothing but "http://server/autoRefresh.do" , then Tomcat should assume the user went away from the computer, and kill the session.

Comment: What does *"session timeout is not working"* mean? The session will time out after being *idle* for 30 minutes. Any request will reset the timer. That's how the session timeout works.

Comment: If you want something in the session to expire 30 minutes after being set, *you* need to capture the update time, and check if time has elapsed. You can't use the session timeout feature for that.

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Edit to explain. I am guessing you mean that you want to close the session if no human-user-generated event has occurred after thirty minutes, and unfortunately the AJAX calls are keeping the session alive (not timing out) despite no human-user activity. If that is what you mean, say that.

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes exactly.

Comment: @MickeyPatel So edit the Question to clarify.

Comment: @BasilBourque Plz check now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use scheduler to forcefully destroy session after 30 minute if you store session creation time. You can start a scheduler on application start up and it will check the sessions which are older than 30 minute will be invalidated.